# When is a JsonNode instance null?

Tags: java, jackson

Consider the following Java class definition.

CrudOperation.java:

```
package com.cyberfront.test.json.nll.demonstration;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class CrudOperation{
    public enum Type {CREATE,UPDATE,DELETE,READ}
    private final Type type;
    private final JsonNode op;

    public CrudOperation(Type type) { this(type, null); }
    public CrudOperation(JsonNode op) { this(Type.UPDATE, op); }

    @JsonCreator
    public CrudOperation(@JsonProperty("type") Type type, @JsonProperty("op") JsonNode op) {
        this.type = type;
        this.op = op;

        boolean isUpdate = Type.UPDATE.equals(this.getType());
        boolean isNotNull = null == this.getOp();
        boolean isValid = isUpdate ^ isNotNull;

        if (!isValid) {
            System.out.println(" isUpdate: " + String.valueOf(isUpdate));
            System.out.println("isNotNull: " + String.valueOf(isNotNull));
            System.out.println("  isValid: " + String.valueOf(isValid));

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operation Failed Validation: " + this.toString());
        }
    }

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public Type getType() { return this.type; };

    @JsonProperty("op")
    public JsonNode getOp() { return this.op; }

    public static <T> String nullCheck(T val) { return null == val ? "null" : val.toString(); }

    public static String toString(Type type, JsonNode op) {
        return "{\"type\":\"" + nullCheck(type) + "\",\"op\":" + nullCheck(op) + "}";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return toString(this.getType(), this.getOp()); }
}
```

In this class, the constructor with the `@JsonCreator` annotation performs validation to ensure there is a non-null `JsonNode` argument `op` exactly when the `type` argument has the value `Type.UPDATE`.  That is, when `type` has value `Type.UPDATE`, `op` should be non-null.  If `type` has any other value, `op` should be null.

Next consider the class below.

Main.java:

```
package com.cyberfront.test.json.nll.demonstration;

import com.cyberfront.test.json.nll.demonstration.CrudOperation.Type;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Main {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CrudOperation createObject = new CrudOperation(Type.CREATE);
        System.out.println("Initial value: " + createObject.toString());

        JsonNode createDocument = mapper.valueToTree(createObject);
        System.out.println("Document value: " + createDocument.toString());

        CrudOperation reconstructedObject = null;
        try {
            reconstructedObject = mapper.treeToValue(createDocument, CrudOperation.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        System.out.println("Reconstructed: " + CrudOperation.nullCheck(reconstructedObject));
    }
}
```

This is used to test the creation of a `CrudOperation` instance with operation type value of `Type.CREATE`, which means `op` should be null.  Yet, this produces the following output:

```
Initial value: {"type":"CREATE","op":null}
Document value: {"@type":"CrudOperation","type":"CREATE"}
 isUpdate: false
isNotNull: false
  isValid: false
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.cyberfront.test.json.nll.demonstration.CrudOperation, problem: Operation Failed Validation: {"type":"CREATE","op":null}
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
Reconstructed: null
```

The initial `CrudOperation` instantiation is validated, and the conversion of that instance to a `JsonNode` instance also works properly.  The problem occurs when attempting to reconstitute the `CrudOperation` instance from the `JsonNode` derived from the original.  For some reason, the value of `op` displays as `null`, but the test for equality with null fails, which in turn causes the `CrudOperation` validation to fail.

Why is happening and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues lies in the meaning of `null` in this context.  In the problematic case, clearly `op` has been instantiated and is therefore not `null`.  This can be shown by adding another output line in the constructor performing the validation:

```
System.out.println("    class:" + (null == op ? "Real Null" : op.getClass().toString()));
```

This, when the program is run again, produces the folloiwng output:

```
Initial value: {"type":"CREATE","op":null}
Document value: {"@type":"CrudOperation","type":"CREATE"}
 isUpdate: false
isNotNull: false
  isValid: false
    class:class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.NullNode
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.cyberfront.test.json.nll.demonstration.CrudOperation, problem: Operation Failed Validation: {"type":"CREATE","op":null}
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
Reconstructed: null
```

That is, `op` is instantiated as a `NullNode` object type, which when the `toString()` method is performed upon it, returns `null` as a string not as the type.

A solution to resolving this is use of the JsonNode.isNull() method to detect when this case arises.

```
@JsonCreator
public CrudOperation(@JsonProperty("type") Type type, @JsonProperty("op") JsonNode op) {
    this.type = type;
    this.op = null == op || op.isNull() ? null : op;

    boolean isUpdate = Type.UPDATE.equals(this.getType());
    boolean isNotNull = null == this.getOp();
    boolean isValid = isUpdate ^ isNotNull;

    if (!isValid) {
        System.out.println(" isUpdate: " + String.valueOf(isUpdate));
        System.out.println("isNotNull: " + String.valueOf(isNotNull));
        System.out.println("  isValid: " + String.valueOf(isValid));
        System.out.println("    class:" + (null == op ? "Real Null" : op.getClass().toString()));

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operation Failed Validation: " + this.toString());
    }
}
```

This additional check for `isNull()` will filter out the case where a JsonNode is an instantiated `null` node, and will provide

```
Initial value: {"type":"CREATE","op":null}
Document value: {"@type":"CrudOperation","type":"CREATE"}
Reconstructed: {"type":"CREATE","op":null}
```

This achieves the desired result.